# EDIT:Setting up environment pr2_gazebo on ubuntu 11.4?

Tags: ros, gazebo-plugin, erratic-gazebo, gazebo-plugins, ros-package-path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a dual boot with Mac OSx 10.6.8 and Ubuntu 11.4, I am attempting to get pr2_gazebo empty_world.lanch up and running.

I am able to rosmake and run gazebo_worlds, but not the specific pr2 simulator.

Here some relevant terminal feed: There seems to be a problem with finding pr2_gazebo (as William said) Any ideas on the source of the problem (and how to fix it)?

catherine@SHERLOCK:~$ rosmake pr2_gazebo
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['pr2_gazebo']
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/catherine/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120527-172708
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['pr2_gazebo'] to:
[]
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The following args could not be parsed as stacks or packages: ['pr2_gazebo']
[ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names.

All input is welcome. Thank you for your time.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34908/edit:setting-up-environment-pr2_gazebo-on-ubuntu-11.4?/) by [cradialline](https://answers.ros.org/users/2463/cradialline/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2012-05-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I fixed it. For some reason all of the stacks were not downloaded although I did the full desktop download, so I downloaded the appropriate stack.
$ sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-pr2-simulator

---

Originally posted by [cradialline](https://answers.ros.org/users/2463/cradialline/) with karma: 16 on 2012-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks like there is a problem finding pr2_gazebo, but that is not your largest problem.

Gazebo from diamondback is known not to work on OS X, in fact gazebo in general does not work on OS X to my knowledge.  However, there is a good chance that Gazebo 1.0.x will work on OS X in the the Fuerte version of ROS, but we are still working on that.

If you want to use gazebo at this time, my advice is to use Ubuntu, either in a VM or use bootcamp to install it along side OS X.

Sorry for the problems on OS X, but I hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2012-05-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1